# Горизонтальный scrollbar в listbox при своей отрисовки содержимого контрола

Tags: c#

**Доброго времени суток, Хэшкодовцы.**

Для цветовой раскраски строк в листбоксе пришлось реализовать свою отрисовку элемента списка.
Для создания многострочного текста в однозаписи, пришлось выставить `DrawMode = OwnerDrawVariable.` Для корректного расчета высоты и ширины строки переопределил `OnMeasureItem`, где рассчитываю высоту и ширину текста через `TextRender`. Вроде правильно все сделал (ну по крайней мере высота элемента списка стала корректно отображаться).
Но вот столкнулся с проблемой, не могу сделать так, чтобы работал горизонтальный скроллбар при длинном тексте. Т.е. в `ItemWidth` вносятся корректные размеры строки, в `OnDrawItem` они уже приходят в размер самого контрола `listbox` (Может не там смотрю?)

В итоге имею, что горизонтальный скроллбар считает, что он не нужен, т.к. вроде как все и влезает на экран. Если увеличить размеры окна, то нормально отрисуется хвост текста, которое в окно не влезло, ну и соответственно при уменьшении окна - хвост текста обрезается, а горизонтальный скроллбар как был неактивен - так и остался.

Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой? В интернете что-то не могу найти как работать с горизонтальным скроллбаром при ручной отрисовки элементов в списке.

**Заранее спасибо за Вашу очередную помощь.**

+++  **UPD** +++

Одним словом, в `OnMeasureItem` я задаю `e.ItemWidth = 654` (это ширина текста)

В `onDrawItem` я вижу `e.Bounds.Width = 567` (это ширина компонента)

+++ **UPD2** +++
Создаю свой класс:

```
public mylistbox()
    : base()
{
    DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
}
```

Переопределил функцию:

```
protected override void OnMeasureItem(MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e != null && e.Index >= 0 && e.Index < Items.Count)
    {
        string str = Items[e.Index].ToString();
        Size sz = TextRenderer.MeasureText(str, Font);
        e.ItemHeight = Math.Max(e.ItemHeight, sz.Height);
        e.ItemWidth = Math.Max(e.ItemWidth, sz.Width);
    }
    else
        base.OnMeasureItem(e);
}
```

И еще одну переопределил:

```
protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e != null && e.Index >= 0 && e.Index < Items.Count)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        string str = Items[e.Index].ToString();
        e.Graphics.DrawString(str, e.Font, new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds.Location);
    }
    else
        base.OnDrawItem(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, как всегда, оказалось просто.

В обработчике событий OnMeasureItem следует добавить:

```
if (HorizontalExtent < sz.Width + 10)
    HorizontalExtent = sz.Width + 10;
```

Где  + 10 - это ширина вертикального скроллбара (иначе хвост текста будет не видно, он перекрывается вертикальным скроллбаром).

Answer (score 0):

пропишите в свойствах 
<имя объекта типа ListBox>.HorizontalScrollbar = true
+ поставьте определение ширины столбца по его содержимому.

должно помочь

Comment: Сделал пример программы. Обновил вопрос. Горизонтальный скроллбар включен. Если использую прорисовку вида: e.Graphics.DrawString(str, e.Font, new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds.Location); - то как я и говорил проблемы со скроллом, не получается его активировать. Если  e.Graphics.DrawString(str, e.Font, new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds); то текст автоматически переносится по словам. Если ничего не получится сделать, то так и оставлю, но хотелось бы горизонтальный скролл активировать.

Comment: Если, как вы говорите, нужно задать размер столбца (которых у меня нет), то мне придется включить MultiColumn, т.к. свойство ColumnWidth в противном случае не используется, а также отказаться от переменно высоты строк, т.к. невозможно задать MultiColumn = true, если DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;